# SubString in reversed index fast!

Tags: c#, arrays, char, substring, reverse

I wonder what is the best way to use substring function on a string in reverse mode?

For example I have a string like:

```
string mainStr= @"CDM\D1_1";
```

Now I want to check if the last two characed are equal to "_1" or not. Note: I dont want to use split on underscore. Just looking for the fastest way to do a reversed substring that is start from last char in string and end to first char. I tried this so far, but not sure if it works!

```
string revStr = new string(mainStr.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
if (revStr.Substring(0, 2) == "_1")
{
   //Do blah blah
}
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry to bother guys but it is Monday you know! so the problem was I should check for "1_" after reversing the array. Yet it better to do with string.EndsWith as suggested below.

Comment: I was going to suggest what you did haha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the built-in [string.EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) method, and [string.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> tried this so far, but not sure if it works!

ehh. Haven't you tested it?

I would use `var index = str.LastIndexOf("_1");`

> Just looking for the fastest way to do a reversed substring that is start from last char in string and end to first char. I tried this so far, but not sure if it works!

You are confusing me. Shouldn't your example contain `sub.Substring(0, 2) == "1_"` in that case?

Comment: OH GOD thanks for your point! I guess I started a bad monday :( I was wresteling with this since morning! Thanks :P

Comment: Just be aware that `LastIndexOf` will also return an index in cases like this: `foo_1bar` which might not be desirable. `EndsWith` seems more appropriate for what was described.

Comment: Yes. I agree. But it can be solved with LastIndexOf too: `if (sub.LastIndexOf("1_") == sub.Length-2)`